# Merge two MongoDB aggregates into one pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of population census and I still don't dominate the “aggregate” function to get the results with just one query.

The collection has [this format](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/tree/v1.0#entrada) (plus a ISO 8601 timestamp). This way, each time a census is conducted we can register the current ages and counts (which can add/modify/delete previous ages).

Now I have two “aggregate” queries [to return this](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/tree/v1.0#get-populationages):

1. [Get the AVG, MAX, MIN of all the registries in the DB.](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/blob/v1.0/app/routes/population.js#L64)
2. [Get each age and show a total (“sum”) of people with that age.](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/blob/v1.0/app/routes/population.js#L80)

However I need to get those results with just one “aggregate” query, but the pipeline is somewhat difficult to me, and I cannot get the statistics and then “unwind” the population to get the sums…

Any help on how to merge this two queries, please? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following aggregation pipeline, it should give you result of the two queries:

```
db.collection('population').aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$population"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "doc": {
                "$push": "$$ROOT"
            },
            "average_age": {
                "$avg": "$population.age"
            },
            "max_age": {
                "$max": "$population.age"
            },
            "min_age": {
                "$min": "$population.age"
            },
            "average_population": {
                "$avg": "$population.count"
            },
            "max_population": {
                "$max": "$population.count"
            },
            "min_population": {
                "$min": "$population.count"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$doc"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$doc.population.age",
            "sum": { "$sum": "$doc.population.count" },
            "average_age": { "$first": "$average_age"},
            "max_age": { "$first": "$max_age"},
            "min_age": { "$first": "$min_age"},
            "average_population": { "$first": "$average_population"},
            "max_population": { "$first": "$max_population"},
            "min_population": { "$first": "$min_population"}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, @chridam! It does! I have to play with it a little bit, so `max_population` is not the max age within each document, but the `$sum` of `population.counts` of each document so I can show at which timestamp/document the most number of people was registered. Anyway, thanks again!!!!

Comment: @Miguel No worries :-) Glad you at least got some ideas from this that will help solve your queries.

Comment: one last question: how do you build these queries? I mean, stage by stage, or building it entirely and then testing? Directly in the mondoDB shell, or any more useful application? As you see I'm still learning with these big queries... :)

Comment: @Miguel What I do personally is run the aggregation query at each pipeline stage, test whether the results tally for each step. So for example, in the aggregation above, I first run `db.collection('population').aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$population"
    }]);` , check the result to see if the `population` array is deconstructed properly, add the next pipeline stage, run that and repeat the steps till you get to the final pipeline step. I use [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) 0.8.4 for this. Once you get a working aggregation pipeline you can then deploy the code to production.